# MKS Cannot connect to integrity client

Tags: java, api, mks

I am trying to connect to MKS Integrity Client using sample code listed below

```
  try
  {
    IntegrationPointFactory ipf = IntegrationPointFactory.getInstance();
    CmdRunner cmdRunner = ipf.createLocalIntegrationPoint().getCommonSession()
                          .createCmdRunner();
    cmdRunner.setDefaultHostname("sslmmks1");
    cmdRunner.setDefaultPort(80);
    cmdRunner.setDefaultUsername("vmenon");
    cmdRunner.setDefaultPassword("Railsonfire1@3");

    Command issuesView = new Command(Command.IM, "issues");
    issuesView.addOption(
      new Option("fields","ID,Type,Summary"));
    issuesView.addOption(
      new Option("query", "Quick Query"));

    Response resp = cmdRunner.execute(issuesView);
    System.out.println(resp);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();

  }
```

I am getting the following error

> com.mks.api.response.ICLaunchException: Cannot connect to Integrity
>   Client, the property IntegrityClient.launchOnDemand is not set to
>   allow automatic launching. at
>   com.mks.connect.ClientCmdRunnerImpl.icInitialize(Native Method) at
>   com.mks.connect.ClientCmdRunnerImpl.checkIntegrityClientForLaunch 
>   (ClientCmdRunnerImpl.java:71) at
>   com.mks.connect.ClientCmdRunnerImpl.executePreCondition(ClientCmdRunnerImpl.java:95)
>   at
>   com.mks.connect.AbstractCmdRunner.executeCommand(AbstractCmdRunner.java:235)
>   at
>   com.mks.connect.AbstractCmdRunner.execute(AbstractCmdRunner.java:394)
>   at org.jpmc.mks.Mksmain.main(Mksmain.java:25)

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you don't have the Integrity Client running and you need to allow automatic launching in the IntegrationPoint.

Please update your code according to the following example:

```
IntegrationPointFactory ipf = IntegrationPointFactory.getInstance();
IntegrationPoint integrPoint = ipf.createLocalIntegrationPoint();
integrPoint.setAutoStartIntegrityClient(true);
CmdRunner cmdRunner = integrPoint.getCommonSession()
                      .createCmdRunner();
```

Also, please follow the **Integrity Integrations Builder Guide (API)** documentation available on your Integrity server (e.g. http://sslmmks1:80 )